# how to calculate $\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin{|x-y|}dxdy$?

Tags: integration, absolute-value

how to calculate $\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin{|x-y|}dxdy$? Can you provide your solution step by step? particularly how to address the absolute.

I do know how to address some similar integral, like

$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\sin|x-\pi/4|dx$
$=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/4}\sin{(\pi/4-x)dx + \int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}}\sin(x-\pi/4)dx$.

But, when it comes to double integral, I am not sure what the $y$ exactly is, and I do not know how to divide the intergal containing an absolute calculation.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you just want to address the absolute value issue, divide the square via the line $x=y$ into two triangles, in each of which one can drop the absolutes and write one of $x-y$ or $y-x$ as appropriate. Then do each integral and add up.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics SE. Take a tour: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour.  You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context by stating what you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959 .

Comment: I add more infomation and the specific issue I have to address

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take values of $(x - y)$ below the line $y = x$, then $y \lt x$ and hence $(x - y)$ will be positive.  So, from symmetry of the region of integration, the integral is, ($a = \dfrac{\pi}{2}$ )

$\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
I &= \displaystyle 2 \int_{x=-a}^{a} \int_{-a}^{x} \sin(x - y) dy dx \\
&= \displaystyle 2 \int_{x = -a}^{a} \cos(x - y) \bigg|_{-a}^{x} dx \\
&= \displaystyle 2 \int_{x = -a}^{a} (1 - \cos(x + a) ) dx \\
&= \displaystyle 2 ( x - \sin(x + a) ) \bigg|_{-a}^{a} \\
&= 2 ( 2 a - \sin(2a) + \sin(0) ) \\
&= 2 (\pi - 0 + 0 ) \\
&= 2 \pi
\end{split}
\end{equation}$

Comment: Very helpful! thanks